# accidentally deleted the default output folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I was rearranging some files in eclipse, and I accidentally deleted the default output folder.  This is the location where eclipse stores the class files.  Can anyone show how to recover it?  Or rebuild it from the .java files?

EDIT:

I just restored the project from backup files.  So this question is no longer relevant.  Unless some future reader did not backup their application before making this same mistake.

Comment: Just re-build your project. This folder is a bin folder that Eclipse uses as its classpath when running your app.

Comment: @Reimeus just eclipse on its own.

Comment: @Reimeus Project->Build Project and Project->Clean did not work.  Eclipse had been storing the classes in some subfolder within WEB-INF.  I changed that to bin in the project properties dialog box.  It asked if I wanted to delete the old files.  I said yes, assuming it would copy them.  But now they don't seem to be coming up when I try rebuild or clean.

Comment: This is why you should use version control.

Answer (score 2):

from the menu bar select:
    Project->Clean...

That will bring up a dialog box to select which projects to rebuild.  The bin directory should be automatically regenerated.

Comment: I have the class folders backed up in another directory I can access through windows explorer.  Can you show me how to work with those backup files? +1 for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Recompile your project, and Eclipse should create it again (default name is bin on some versions)

If not, navigate to your project settings, and go to

`Java Build Path > Source`and at the bottom you will see the ***default output folder***. You can create it again by using the ***Browse*** button, and then ***Create new folder***

Comment: The contents have been destroyed.  Not just the file.  See my comment above.

Comment: Did you check on webapp project settings which is the output folder ?

Comment: I have the class folders backed up in another directory I can access through windows explorer.  Can you show me how to work with those backup files?

Comment: Working with a backup of the class folders is useless, since they will get recreated once the project is compiled again. You should verify which is your output folder on the project settings, check if it exists, or create it if it doesn't.

Comment: Just to understand better, can you post a picture of your project structure, and explain which folder is lost or not working ?

Comment: I found them in the folder I created.  Thank you.  But the problem is that I am getting 500 errors when I try to run the files in the web browser.  Perhaps because I changed the name of the default output folder? Where do I look to change the reference to the classes folder? myapp.xml docbase? web.xml does not seem to have anything for that.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is re-compile your project, For that you can select your Project and do `Ctrl+B` or just select `Project->Build Project`

**EDIT:**
As you mention in the comments that you still do not see the class files. Please check the *Default output folder* by selecting your project Right-click `Build Path -> Configure build path...` then select `Source` tab and see what the `Default output folder:` mentioned there, your class files must be created there.

Comment: That just gives me an empty folder because the files were deleted.  I have the class folders backed up in another directory I can access through windows explorer.  Can you show me how to work with those backup files?

Comment: Do you see any error in your project in eclipse? otherwise there is no reason for class files to not be generated.

Comment: The class files seem to be generated.  But I moved them to a bin folder in the root of the project.  And now I am getting 500 errors and 404 errors when I try to run the application in the browser.  Where do I look to find the place where the web container references the class files?  there is a docbase tag in myapp.xml, but changing that does not seem to have an effect.